# regex help: Balance 123,33 p. => 123.33 (double)

Tags: java, regex, double

I'm new in **regex**..

How can I parse the string through regex

```
Balance 123,45 p.
```

to `double` `123.45`

Comment: is it a comma in 124,45?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with `space` as a delimilter and than use [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to replace `,` with `.`.

After that use [parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29).It returns,

> Returns a new double initialized to the value represented by the
>   specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Double.

```
String number = "Balance 123,45 p.";
String[] number_array = number.split(" ");

String str = (number_array[1].replaceAll(",","."));
double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
System.out.println(d);
```

Output = `123.45`

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** Not a Regex based solution.

To me it seems that the String that you are getting is from a locale where decimal separator is `,` instead of `.`, you can just do something like this:

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
    Number n = nf.parse("123,45");
    Double d = n.doubleValue();
    System.out.print(d);
```

Comment: +1 I think this should be the right way to do the number parsing.

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d*(,\d+)?)
```

This will match zero or more numbers followed by optionally a comma and one or more numbers. e.g: `1,2345; 123; 12,34; ,25 (leading zero may be omitted)`

You can then replace the comma with a dot (`string.replace(',', '.')`) and do what you want with it :)

Comment: @RanRag I saw it as well afterwards and modified my answer. :) Doing too much with PHP..

Comment: maybe `(\d*(?:,\d+)?)`, I assume the entire thing should be captured, not just the portion after the comma.

Answer (score 1):

Search for `Balance (\d*),(\d*) p\.`
Replace with `double \$1.\$2`

This works in IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.lang.Double;

public class RegExpTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "Balance 123,45 p.";

        String p = "Balance (\\d+),(\\d+) p";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()){
             System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1)+"."+matcher.group(2)));
        }   
    }   
}
```